# Eclipse Android SDK slow Content Assist performance

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, content-assist

Im running eclipse on my windows 7 machine, 64bit with 6gb ram and core 2 duo.
Im currently running Eclipse 3.6 and android 2.2 SDK
Im running jdk 1.6

Im noticing that when coding and the context popups to list methods of a class, it hangs Eclipse for up to 15 seconds. This is very frustrating.

One thing to note, when Eclipse hangs, my processor is maxed out, and is being worked by a java process. So its doing something whatever it is. But frequently everytime I finish an object with a period and the context box pops up, its becoming too painful to work with.

I changed some settings in the Eclipse.ini file such as:
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 512m

Is there anything else I should look at:

Comment: Interested in this myself as well. I have the same experience. Remember reading something that one should make sure to have the latest  java version (build 1.6.0_21-b07), but I still experience lag when intellisense pops up (but it seems to be only for Android related classes, not for "pure" Java classes, or my own classes). I think also increasing the MaxPermSize has been a suggested solution, but I haven't found this to work either.

Comment: I have this problem too. I ran SysInternals Process Monitor which shows it trying to repeatedly open `SDK\platforms\android-4\sources` repeatedly, which doesn't exist. I'm going to try Eclipse 3.5 as the answer suggests.

Comment: Given Nick's information, I wonder if just creating `SDK\platforms\android-4\sources` would have solved the issue? or if that didn't work, I would have tried duplicating the existing `SDK\platforms\android-1.6` and renamed it `SDK\platforms\android-4`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=known+issues+ADT+Eclipse+Helios)

I have been able to find the [bug report from Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=325829).

In short:

- It is a problem that arises when using Helios with ADT. As the [ADT page on android.com](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) says:

> **Caution:** There are known issues with the ADT plugin running with Eclipse 3.6. Please stay on 3.5 until further notice.

- To fix it, you will have to use Eclipse 3.5 and put your project in a newly created workspace. (If you keep the workspace from Eclipse 3.6, the problem will occur even on Eclipse 3.5.)

Comment: Thanks jhominal, downgrading to Galileo solved it for me. Perhaps a bit slow of me not to notice that from the Eclipse-ADT page, but they could have put it in *big red letters* or something ;)

Comment: the problem also exists on Juno

Answer (score 4):

A Work-around procedure is presented in comment#8 at this URL: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7850

Example:

I'm coding against Froyo, and my target SdkVersion is 7 (AndroidManifest.xml). So for step 1, I downloaded this file:

```
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+archive/froyo-release.tar.gz
```

And then for step 2, I extracted the base/ directory of that .tgz file into my SDK path, which I install under /opt/android-sdk-linux_x86/. So here's the command I executed against the tgz to put everything where it goes:

```
tar -vzxf base-froyo.tar.gz -C /opt/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-7/sources/ base/
```

The end goal appears to be to place the actual sources into the "sources" folder in the SDK tree, so that when the auto-correct goes out looking for them, they are there.

snpe60 describes it more clearly:

> Comment 7 by snpe60, Oct 14, 2010
>   This issue is happen because the ADT
>   classpath container have an invalid
>   source attachment by default. It is
>   fixed in
>   https://review.source.android.com/16569.
>   This change enables changing the ADT
>   clasppath container's source
>   attachment and disables setting
>   invalid source attachment. Hoping it
>   will be available in ADT 8.0.0.

Comment: [Comment 19](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7850#c19) suggests that just creating an empty `sources` folder will fix the slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

This is much better [Eclipse autocompletion problem](http://nepnux.dyndns.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=50%3ahow-to-fix-slow-autocomplete-feature-autocompletion-hang-in-eclipse-361-helios-for-android-development&catid=34%3ahow-tos&Itemid=55)

Answer (score 0):

here is a link for the problem you are having

http://aaarkonusurum.blogspot.com/2011/08/eclipse-intelisensein-cldrtan-yavaslgna.html