# Android eclipse plugin lags on type (3.6 - Helios)

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, lag, content-assist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse Android SDK slow Content Assist performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953012/eclipse-android-sdk-slow-content-assist-performance)

When I write a code like so:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
tv.                                    // Here auto-complete window appears, and laaaaag,
// and lag and lag, 
//and eclipse status of background working is "Calculating Additional Info"
```

On my Windows7 in ResourceMonitor i can see that eclipse.exe is waiting for TCP in-out.

Anybody can help me? Thanls in advance!!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot offer a solution but I would like to say that I also have this problem. In fact, I have this problem in general with Eclipse, not just Android. Writing a java console application tends to lag when I try to invoke intellisense. I've trained myself to type out the method name quick enough so intellisense doesn't try and kick on. Unfortunately that's a problem too when you don't know what you're looking for :)

Comment: @Jason L.: in Eclipse, content assist only kicks in when you explicitly invoke it via Ctrl + Space. Not sure what you mean by having to be quick enough.

Comment: @Zsolt Török: that is not really true. If you reach a point where content assist would get offered which usually is be typing a period then the content assist automatically pops up. Maybe you have turned it off like me.

Comment: @Zsolt I've actually noticed that Eclipse kicks in with its intellisense when I type the dot after a variable (ie: someVar.). At that point, if I wait a second, I see the intellisense pop up (i.e content assist). If the object I'm working with as a lot of methods this list can take upwards of a minute to load, and the eclipse process spikes. It's not a huge deal as I've found a way around. And also, I'll now be downgrading to Eclipse 3.5 as that seems to fix the Android issue (which may fix my other issue as well) =)

Comment: I have the same problem, and not only with Android, but maybe worse with Android. It is a **very annoying** thing with Eclipse.

Comment: @Octavian Damiean and @Jason L.: point taken, forgot that one after the dot.

Answer (score 3):

The Android eclipse plug in has known issues with 3.6, get 3.5(Galileo).

Comment: +1 I tried with Eclipse 3.5 and it works better than Eclipse 3.6.

Comment: thx guys!I thought so but hoped another)

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue that has been fixed in the upcoming release of Eclipse Helios SR2, and the patch has been back-ported. If you'd like to fix it yourself, see this [thread on android-developers mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/0f9d2a852e661cba). It involves copying a jar to Eclipse's plugins folder.

Comment: Ditto - This worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd rather not downgrade from 3.6, try this workaround, it has worked for many (me included):

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7850&q=adt&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars#c8

Comment: [Comment 19](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7850#c19) suggests that just creating an empty `sources` folder will fix the slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced and set the flag to “Type Proposals”

IT WORKS! Win 7, Helios Version: 3.6.1, Android, Java jre6

Comment: Thank you! I do not try it yet but your "IT WORKS" makes me believe=)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't works for me(( go down on 3.5 for android