# Eclipse ContentAssist suddenly very, very slow

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse Android SDK slow Content Assist performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953012/eclipse-android-sdk-slow-content-assist-performance)

For reasons not worth discussing here, I rely heavily on ContentAssist in my Android development under Eclipse. When I first starting using it last summer, I had Ganymede running on an old, slow XP system and ContentAssist would effectively lock everything up for 10-20 seconds or more when I was referencing an object with a large inheritance hierarchy and many methods (e.g., types of Android Views, Context, etc.).

To make life easier I upgraded my PC to a new quad-core system with 8Gb memory running Windows 7 Pro, and Eclipse then ran like lightning; problem solved, or so I thought.

The other day, everything suddenly seemed to have slowed down again, to the point where ContentAssist is again hanging up for several seconds at a time when I reference complex objects. The only recent changes that I have made have been to upgrade my development environment to the latest Android SDK and toolset, plus installing Eclipse Helios.

So is it the Helios upgrade that did it? I upgraded a few weeks ago, but I just noticed this recently when I started doing a bunch of new development work. What would I have to do to go back to Ganymede if I can't figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem like this a few weeks ago and it was due to ADT giving Eclipse some invalid information about where the Android sources are for the classpath. I fixed it by downloading the Android sources and attaching them myself. The bug is here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7850

and a blog post on how to attach the sources is here:

http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/

Comment: Thanks. It was obviously the ADT upgrade that broke things, but since I had changed two things at once, I didn't know which one to investigate further. I'm following the instructions now...